# Spring boot - Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I want to consume soap service using jaxb. 
The generated request from jaxb is

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:Add xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ns2:intA>10</ns2:intA><ns2:intB>20</ns2:intB>
      </ns2:Add>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But the response is a soap exception as stated in the title.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
```

Below is my soap config code. Source example: [https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-soap-client-webservicetemplate/](http://Spring%20Boot%20Soap%20Client)

```
    public class ConsumeSoapApplication {
            public static String wsdlurl = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl";
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                    JAXBContext.newInstance(com.dxc.service.soap.service.calc.ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName(),
                            com.dxc.service.soap.service.calc.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader());
                } catch (JAXBException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SpringApplication.run(ConsumeSoapApplication.class, args);
            }

            @Bean
            CommandLineRunner lookup(SoapConnector soapConnector) {
                return args -> {
                    Integer a = 10;
                    Integer b = 20;
                    if(args.length>0){
                        a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                        b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                    }

                    Add add = new Add();
                    add.setIntA(a);
                    add.setIntB(b);
                    AddResponse addRes = (AddResponse) soapConnector.callWebService(wsdlurl, add);
                    System.out.println("Got Response As below ========= : ");
                    System.out.println("Added result : "+addRes.getAddResult());
                };
            }
        }

@Configuration
public class SoapConfig {    
    @Bean
        public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
            try {
                JAXBContext jb = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.dxc.service.soap.service.calc.ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName(),
                        com.dxc.service.soap.service.calc.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader());
                //Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = (Jaxb2Marshaller) jb.createMarshaller();
                Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
                marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.dxc.service.soap.service.calc");
                //marshaller.setContextPath("com.dxc.service.soap.calc");
                return marshaller;
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            return null;
        }

        @Bean
        public SoapConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
            SoapConnector client = new SoapConnector();
            client.setDefaultUri("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx");
            client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
            client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
            return client;
        }
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you're facing is that the web service at http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx expects a `SOAPAction` header. And since you're not providing one the service have no idea how to route the request.

The tutorial you're following doesn't require the `SOAPAction` header to do the routing.

If you take a look at how the `Add` operation is specified in the the [WSDL](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl), you'll find the expected value of the `SOAPAction` header there. Same for all the other operations the service provides.

```
<wsdl:operation name="Add">                                                           
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Add" style="document" />             
  <wsdl:input>                                                                        
    <soap:body use="literal" />                                                       
  </wsdl:input>                                                                       
  <wsdl:output>                                                                       
    <soap:body use="literal" />                                                       
  </wsdl:output>                                                                      
</wsdl:operation>
```

Assuming that your `SoapConnector` class is identical to the one in [the tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-soap-client-webservicetemplate/) you can remove the `String url` as input to the `callWebservice` method since that is already set via the `client.setDefaultUri("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx");` in the `SoapConnector` bean. Instead, add `String soapAction` as an input parameter, giving you the following

```
public class SOAPConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public Object callWebService(Object request, String soapAction){
        return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, new SoapActionCallback(soapAction));
    }
}
```

Then, remove the `wsdlurl` as input to `soapConnector.callWebService` (it was wrong anyway) and add the `soapHeader` value for the operation you want to use instead, leaving you with this

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner lookup(SoapConnector soapConnector) {
    return args -> {
        Integer a = 10;
        Integer b = 20;
        if(args.length>0){
            a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }

        Add add = new Add();
        add.setIntA(a);
        add.setIntB(b);
        AddResponse addRes = (AddResponse) soapConnector.callWebService(add, "http://tempuri.org/Add");
        System.out.println("Got Response As below ========= : ");
        System.out.println("Added result : "+addRes.getAddResult());
    };
}
```

Of course, if you want to use other operations besides `Add` you'll have to tweak this solution to make it generic.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. You saved my day..  \(‾▿‾\)

Answer (score 1):

@Misantorp answer is solution to call SOAP webservice where action has to be passed.
I used the same advise and could call temperature converter of w3School.

[a link] https://github.com/suhelm/SPRINGBOOT/tree/main/SOAP_temparature_converter